# Preventing Facebook Social Login if email found

Tags: facebook-connect

My site has two types of users a business and regular(non-business).
The regular can also login via Facebook social login.

Consider the following flow: A business user registers first **and then the same user** goes to create a regular user account w Facebook Social login... **this is the scenario I am trying to prevent**.

I want to prevent this by checking the email and if this allready exists.

So consider this UX path and tell me what you think

1. The Business User clicks the FB login button...the auth dialog appears.
2. With FB.API call I get his email
3. On clicking OK I make an ajax request and check for the e-mail in the DB.
4. If found prevent registration and call FB.logout to log him out of FB.

Ideally i must check the email before the popup appearing...nonetheless I have not found a way getting the email from FB,API **before** a connection is made to FB...something that will inevitably bring up the dialogue...

What do you think?

Comment: Why do you need to prevent this situation? There are sites where I have six or seven different accounts (not SE, just one is enough  ).

Comment: @Danielillo what SE means...

Comment: I am talking about the case where someone goes to create an account w the same email....in most sites if you go to create an account w the same email....this is denied

Comment: Well, the question issue is about two different login credentials: personal email and FB account. If the FB account shares the same email I think is not a problem for your company, nor do I understand how it can harm it. SE = Stack Exchange